# Can multiple threads wait on one object at once?

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor

If wait can only be called from a synchronized context, and you can only call wait on an object while holding its lock, then how can multiple threads wait on the same object? Furthermore, since notify must also be called from a synchronized context, how can the notify occur?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wait method *releases* the lock on the object on which it is waiting.  Once released, another object can then acquire the lock and also wait or notify.  And, this is all [right there in the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29).

Comment: even i feel sheepish too!!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but instead of using the wait method, you could use the [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) class in the concurrent package introduce on Java 5. You can initialize the `CountDownLatch` on the class you are going to wait for, and methods waiting for it should execute the method await(), and to release the latch you invoke the method countDown(). It is more clean and clear than using wait() in my opinion. The Effective Java book has a really interesting topic about this class.

Comment: Make sure you test the performance (profile execution) of these new concurrent classes "CountDownLatch" & "CyclicBarrier". They are super easy to use but at a cost. I was able to triple my performance however it took me about solid 8 hours to implement with heavy unit testing.

Comment: This is actually the answer I was looking for, which answers the subject of the question. I think the question details are evidence of going down the wrong path.